# JasperReport File Not Found error in fat jar

Tags: java, swing, report

I made a fat jar that contains JasperReport but when I try to execute the jar this pop's out in the cmd

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.jar!\fxml\Report.jrxml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

the "!" makes the problem here I think, but I don't know why it is added to the path nor how to remove it.

Here is my code:

```
public class PrintReport extends JFrame {
public void showReport(Connection conn) throws JRException {
    String reportSrcFile = getClass().getResource("/fxml/Report.jrxml").getFile();
    String reportsDir = getClass().getResource("/fxml/").getFile();

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSrcFile);
    // Fields for resources path
    HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("reportsDirPath", reportsDir);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    list.add(parameters);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
    JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
    viewer.setOpaque(true);
    viewer.setVisible(true);
    this.add(viewer);
    this.setSize(1000, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are not accessible as `File` once you package them in a jar. Load the report from an `InputStream` instead of a file instead:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fxml/Report.jrxml"));
```

As for the parameter: Try using resource paths, if it's used to resolve resources in your report file. JasperReports should be able to access resources via `ClassLoader`.